# How to use Query function to get dates between two dates alongside the corresponding data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to convert my data format from something like this:

[Original Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg54A.png)

To something like this:

[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JEfq.png)

So the end state is: the dates between the start and end dates in B and C listed out, with the corresponding 'ID' and 'Number' in adjacent columns.

I have been able to get the dates listed out using `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(C2:C10,B2:B10)>=SEQUENCE(1,1000,0),B2:B10+SEQUENCE(1,1000,0),"")),"where Col1 is not null"))`. But I can't figure out how to get the 'ID' and 'Number' as well.

[Here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1riSJQ5Yy28-TZRzOemzE3nAp14_MJDMHpwlEEi_mEaQ/edit#gid=0) the sample data for reference - appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(index(match(,0/(A2:A<>"")))),lambda(f,q,vstack(f,let(a,index(A2:A,q),b,index(B2:B,q),c,index(C2:C,q),d,index(D2:D,q),Σ,c-b+1,
        hstack(wrapcols(a,Σ,a),sequence(Σ,1,b),wrapcols(d,Σ,d))))))
```

[image]

Comment: That's worked great! Appreciate your help